# foreign key in migration is needed to let has_many belong_to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

do i need to create foreign key in migration to let has_many belong_to work?
Can i don't create any foreign key such as :options => "CONSTRAINT fk_box_storage REFERENCES box(id)" and still have use has_many and belong_to in model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to, if you are only going to have a web app accesing the database. In case you want to access the db with another app or directly I would recommend you DO create the foreign keys since they will give you a better insight of what is going on there and won't let you insert wrong information or delete by error (in case you set up the on delete option)

Comment: you mean the a.destroy delete? or the :dependent => :destroy ?

Comment: In Rails the delete will only delete the single record and destroy will delete the record and the children. But additionally when you enter to your db via console or a GUI if for some reason you try to delete a record it won't let you if that will cause leaving any foster children.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create any such constraint. You just need to create a stand-alone migration to create the join table.
Lets say, you have 2 models with habtm, User and Role.

```
>> script/generate migration roles_users
```

In your migration

```
create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :role
end
```

That's it !

Comment: Because the id primary key is not needed.